# Performance issue with c# ToList()

Tags: c#, linq

I have this block of code. My data is around 20000 tokens. And I am sending them 1000 and 1000. I am haing performance issues here. What can I do here to make it perform better? Should I try cutting back on the use of .ToList()

```
var badgewiseGroup = tokensWithoutOnbehlfOf.GroupBy(x => x.BadgeCount);
foreach (var bGroup in badgewiseGroup)
{
    var badgeTokensWithoutOnbehlfOf = bGroup.Select(x => x).ToList();
    while (badgeTokensWithoutOnbehlfOf.Any())
    {
        var tokens = badgeTokensWithoutOnbehlfOf.Take(numberToTake).ToList();

        Log.Log(EventSeverity.Informational, $"Processing Push notification for MessageId:{pushContent.MessageId}, Username:{tokens.FirstOrDefault().Username}," +
            $" OnBehalfOf:{tokens.FirstOrDefault().OnBehalfOf}, Id:{tokens.FirstOrDefault().Id}, DeviceId:{tokens.FirstOrDefault().DeviceId}, " +
            $"Token:{tokens.FirstOrDefault().Token}, ");

        pushContent.Title = msgTitle;
        pushContent.Body = msgBody;
        var message = new Messaging.Message();

        var androidToken = tokens.Where(x => x.OsVersion != null && x.OsVersion.ToLower().Contains("android")).ToList();

        if (androidToken != null && androidToken.Any())
        {
            message = GetAndroidMessageNotifictationObject(androidToken, pushContent);
            SendMessage(message, pushContent.MessageId);
        }

        var iosToken = tokens.Where(x => x.OsVersion != null && x.OsVersion.ToLower().Contains("ios")).ToList();
        if (iosToken != null && iosToken.Any())
        {
            message = GetIOSMessageNotifictationObject(iosToken, pushContent);
            SendMessage(message, pushContent.MessageId);
        }

        var oldTokens = tokens.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.OsVersion)).ToList();
        if (oldTokens != null && oldTokens.Any())
        {
            message = GetOldAppUsersMessageNotifictationObject(oldTokens, pushContent);
            SendMessage(message, pushContent.MessageId);
        }


        badgeTokensWithoutOnbehlfOf = badgeTokensWithoutOnbehlfOf.Skip(numberToTake).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: One easy optimization: instead of `x.OsVersion.ToLower().Contains("ios")` use `IndexOf` which takes a `StringComparison` parameter and doesn't need to allocate a new string every time.

Comment: Also, the answer to your question is "Yes", especially this one `bGroup.Select(x => x).ToList()` and this one `badgeTokensWithoutOnbehlfOf.Skip(numberToTake).ToList()`.  But why don't you just try it and profile it and see? We don't know if your code is memory constrained or CPU constrained. We can assume `OsVersion` is a string, but it could be an expensively generated property. etc. etc

Comment: You need to figure out where the majority of the time is being spent and work on _that_. You can try things like grouping lots of 1000 rather than recreating a list each time, but without knowing what `GetAndroidMessageNotifictationObject` or `SendMessage` do, it's impossible to know if that will make a significant difference.

Comment: Also, you call `tokens.FirstOrDefault()` 5 times when constructing the log message. It would be a little faster to just call it once and save the result locally before creating the message.

Comment: `pushContent.Title = msgTitle; pushContent.Body = msgBody;` <- These lines appear to be reassigning the same values on each iteration. They probably get optimized by the compiler (?) but should likely be done before the loop since they don't change on the iterations.

Answer (score 0):

If execute order is not important and u use `.Net Core` u can try use action block for this.

```
var blockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 48,
    SingleProducerConstrained = true,
    EnsureOrdered = true
};

ActionBlock<TypeInList> block = null;
block = new ActionBlock<TypeInList>(bGroup => 
{
    //your bGroup code
}, blockOptions);

tokensWithoutOnbehlfOf.ForEach(bGroup => block.Post(bGroup));
```

More info about ActionBlock u can find here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-1.0